# ASP.Net Fw 4.0 CertEnroll API The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-4.0, certificate, certenroll

Implementing Certificates with CertEnroll dll on an Asp.net fw 4 website:

```
    CX509CertificateRequestPkcs10 objPkcs10 = new CX509CertificateRequestPkcs10Class();
    CX509PrivateKey objPrivateKey = new CX509PrivateKeyClass();
    CCspInformation objCSP = new CCspInformationClass();
    CCspInformations objCSPs = new CCspInformationsClass();
    CX500DistinguishedName objDN = new CX500DistinguishedNameClass();
    CX509Enrollment objEnroll = new CX509EnrollmentClass();
    CObjectIds objObjectIds = new CObjectIdsClass();
    CObjectId objObjectId = new CObjectIdClass();
    CX509ExtensionKeyUsage objExtensionKeyUsage = new CX509ExtensionKeyUsageClass();
    CX509ExtensionEnhancedKeyUsage objX509ExtensionEnhancedKeyUsage = new CX509ExtensionEnhancedKeyUsageClass();
    string strRequest;


    try
    {

        //  Initialize the csp object using the desired Cryptograhic Service Provider (CSP)
        objCSP.InitializeFromName(
            "Microsoft Enhanced Cryptographic Provider v1.0"
        );
        //  Add this CSP object to the CSP collection object
        objCSPs.Add(
            objCSP
        );
        //  Provide key container name, key length and key spec to the private key object
        //objPrivateKey.ContainerName = "AlejaCMa";
        objPrivateKey.Length = 1024;
        objPrivateKey.KeySpec = X509KeySpec.XCN_AT_SIGNATURE;
        objPrivateKey.KeyUsage = X509PrivateKeyUsageFlags.XCN_NCRYPT_ALLOW_ALL_USAGES;
        objPrivateKey.MachineContext = false;


        //  Provide the CSP collection object (in this case containing only 1 CSP object)
        //  to the private key object
        objPrivateKey.CspInformations = objCSPs;

        //  Create the actual key pair
        objPrivateKey.Create();
......
```

It is throwing the following error message (on the last line)

```
Certificate Error CertEnroll::CX509PrivateKey::Create: The system cannot find the file specified. 0x80070002 (WIN32: 2 ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)
```

When debugging it passes the instruction Create() without errors... but on my test environment: Windows Server 2012  it is failing

source: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alejacma/archive/2008/09/05/how-to-create-a-certificate-request-with-certenroll-and-net-c.aspx

Comment: Can you test this on another environment to see if the problem is with the environment or something else?

Comment: I am having the same problem on my dev environment.. :/

Comment: Related posts - For on-premise deployement : [CryptographicException was unhandled: System cannot find the specified file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17840825/465053). For Azure deployment : [Certenroll on Azure - Generating self signed certificates](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58800004/465053)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this by setting Load User Profile = True in IIS advanced settings

See [Tim Erikson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8787/tim-erickson) answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2741345/386107)